# How to check for nested hash arguments using with constraint in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test if a nested hash argument passed to a method is containing my element

```rb
hash_argument = { 
                  body: {  
                         my_element: 'some_value',
                         some_other_element: 'some_other_value
                        }
                 }
```

I tried

```rb
expect(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).with(hash_including(body: hash_including(my_element: 'some_value'))
```

but this doesn't work.

gem details

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
```

Comment: are you sure hash_argument has symbol keys and not strings?

Comment: turns out hash inside body was serialized into string

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what is wrong with your test. But, I have tried to simulate one theoretical scenario using some pieces of your example.

*my_class.rb*
[image]

*my_class_spec.rb*
[image]

and the test has passed:
[image]

I was also able to check the test failing:
[image]

I tested using this configuration:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    diff-lcs (1.5.0)
    rspec (3.11.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.11.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.11.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.11.0)
    rspec-core (3.11.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.11.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.11.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.11.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.11.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.11.0)
    rspec-support (3.11.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-21

DEPENDENCIES
  rspec

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.14
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and explaining in detail, Turns out hash inside body was serialized into string so 
now i check `hash_including(body: string_including("my_string"))` and this works.